# How Can I Create Microsoft Word And PowerPoint App in Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I want to make a Website in flutter web which can create Word and PowerPoint documents using some data in specific design and templates.

fore this I tried some libraries i.e [docx_template](https://pub.dev/packages/docx_template) and [flutter_pptx](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_pptx) but the problem with the docx_template is its implements io.dart which can't work in Flutter web.

and the problem with flutter_pptx is I can't able to create ppt with specific design and Template.

Answer (score -1):

flutter_pptx saves the result into a byte array. They just add an example for saving with dart:io. You can save these bytes in another way which works on web. (Maybe you have to ask the user to pick a file from the system and then you can write bytes into that file. I'm not sure about it because I'm not a web developer)